# Get the path of path/filname but where the file has no extension

Tags: java, path

I can have the following filename with path:

/somepath/file

The file has no extension, so in Java getPath ends up returning the entire path and filename. Assuming that the last thing in the path/filename is always a filename, how can I extract the path? The simplest solution is just to look for the last forward slash. But is there a built-in API that gets it?

**Edit:** Mistake. I meant how do I extract the path (and not the filename). Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()`

```
System.out.println(fileObj.getPath().substring(0, f.getPath().lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Edit : Just found out the existence of `getParent()` and it will give you that directory of the file directly.

```
System.out.println(fileObj.getParent());
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant get the path.

Answer (score 2):

```
     File file = new File("/somepath/file");
     file.getName();
```

Edit : If you want path try this

```
    file.getCanonicalPath();
```

Also you could use properties on file object to extract various type of file related data.

Comment: This is a much better way to get the name. +1

Comment: Sorry, I meant get the path.

Answer (score 2):

With Java SE 7:

```
Path path = Paths.get("/somepath/file");
String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();

Path parentPath = path.getParent();
```

**Edit:**

Note: Depending what you are doing, consider not to hard-code the root directory (here: "/") and the separator (here: "/") and make sure the code is platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getName()` method in class `File`.

Answer (score 0):

Use getParent()

`File file = new File("/somepath/file");
    file.getParent();`

This will give you "/somepath" back.